# É possivel ocultar parametros da URL com PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tenho um projeto em php com codeigniter que recebe `dominio.com/?id=212454&survey=complete` 
e depois que eu guardo esses dados em uma variavel, eu queria retirar isto da url, ficando apenas `dominio.com`

Meu controller atual esta assim:

```
    <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $parameters = $this->input->get();
        if(isset($parameters['id'])){
            if(filter_var($parameters['id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) || (preg_match("/\(?\d{2}\)?\s?\d{5}\-?\d{4}/", $parameters['id']))){
                //o email ou telefone é valido
                $this->load->view('index',[
                    'survey'=>$parameters['survey'],
                ]); 
            }else{
                $this->load->view('semvariavel');
            };

        }else{
            $this->load->view('semvariavel');
        };

    }
}
```

Estou usando a seguinte solução no front-end:

```
    <script>    
    if(typeof window.history.pushState == 'function') {
        window.history.pushState({}, "Hide", '<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Qual servidor web está usando? Apache?

Comment: Passa os dados por post ao invéz de get

Comment: @bfavaretto sim

Comment: @WotonSampaio não é possivel, vai ser um link tipo ref,a  pessoa ja entra com os parametros

Comment: Veja se o conteúdo na página que indiquei como duplicata resolvem o seu problema. Se não resolver, me avise aqui.

Comment: @bfavaretto tentei não funcionou

Comment: É meio estranho isso que você descreve que quer fazer...

Comment: é uma pagina de pesquisa, não quero que a pessoa veja o ref dela depois que entrar na pagina

Comment: Talvez um redirecionamento pelo PHP, então?

Comment: As duas possibilidades são, 1. após o load da página executar history.pushState - 2. usar Ajax e não páginar - Extra: claro que vc pode também optar por usar URLs amigáveis, o que tecnicamente seriam ainda urls diferentes, pode ser o que procura pode ser que não.

Comment: Parece que a solução é apenas front end mesmo, o problema é que fazendo isso no front, estou obtendo url.com/index.php, mas acho que consigo resolver isso com .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não consegue realizar alterações no navegador pelo PHP, pois o PHP é processado no servidor, e não no cliente (browser).

O que você pode é executar um script javascript nesta view que faça isso, já que o javascript sim, é executado do lado do cliente.

Uma maneira de fazer isso é com o o comando `history.pushState`, mas apenas em navegadores que tem o suporte a esta ação. Exemplo:

```
history.pushState({},"URL Rewrite Example","https://stackoverflow.com/example")
```

Você pode saber mais sobre o método pushState() em: [Mozilla Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState%28%29.C2.A0method)